# How can I suppress output of a bash script from within the script itself?

Tags: bash

I have a script that connects to an FTP server and while doing so prints out a load of junk.

Is there a way to 'mute' the ouput of the script, similar to windows `@echoff`? I saw on another question very similar to mine, not the same though that you could use `scriptname >/dev/null`. When I put this in my program, obviously replacing `scriptname` with the name of the script, I got a `command not found` error message.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening.

Comment: Because of a typo, for example. Or because the script calls a command that's not available, in which case the shell will print the error message to stderr as opposed to stdout (which is not redirected by `> /dev/null`). Without knowing your code and the way you call it, all is guesswork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't put that in your program, but rather, would use it when calling your program. On the command line:

```
$ scriptname >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 5):

If you mean you want to redirect all output to `/dev/null` from *within the script*, rather than when you execute the script, you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Hi
```

and run that, like this

```
./script
```

then do this

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 1> /dev/null
echo Hi
```

and run it again exactly the same way, and see that the output is discarded.